# Double number returns stackoverflow

Tags: java, function, double, stack-overflow

The highest number that `double` can represent is extremely high, I thought.
Though following code throws an exception. It's actually my full code.

```
public class Summe {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(summe(20000));
  }

public static double summe(double s) {
    return s == 0 ? s : s + summe(s-1); 
  }
}
```

Thanks for the answers so far. My question is: How can I make my code work?

Comment: Range of double has nothing to do with it. You recurrently call `summe` 20k times overflowing stack. Also... What is you actual question?

Comment: How many times do you think `summe` is being called before it returns?

Comment: Don't use equality checks on doubles.

Comment: I think summe gets called around 20000 times. Where is the limit of a stack ?

Answer (score 5):

The problem here isn't the size of number a `double` can hold - the problem is the size of the stack. Here, you have 20K nested call to `summe`, which is **way** too much for the stack to handle, and hence, it overflows. If `s` were an `int` instead of a `double`, you'd have the exact same problem.

Comment: And the fact that he's using exact comparison on floating-point doesn't help the base case.

Comment: @chrylis: The base case is absolutely fine.  20000 - 1 (etc.) will be calculated without any loss of precision.

Comment: @chrylis Good point, even though in this case it coincidentally works.

Comment: As a note, on my machine the stack falls over after 6279 calls.

Comment: My stack overflows at 5300. 5299 still works fine. Thats weird

Answer (score 0):

You made too many recursive call to `summe`.

You should read this question carefully to get a full explanation : [What is a StackOverflowError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stack-overflow-error)